# Installed Let's Encrypt as standalone but want to use as Apache

Tags: apache, debian, lets-encrypt

I followed this guide to set-up Let's Encrypt https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates

I created the certificate for one of my sites using:

`sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com`

and now need to add it to Apache. I started following [this guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu) but it lists different certificate extensions.

I've just found the following article https://www.upcloud.com/support/install-lets-encrypt-apache/ which seems like a more straight forward process.

What's the best way to remove what I've done so far and go this alternative route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide https://certbot.eff.org/#debianjessie-apache

and when it took me through the install process it allowed me to update the existing certificate.